# lag function with variable n

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, lead

I am having some problems using the `lag` function in `dplyr`. This is my dataset.

```
ID <- c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300)
daytime <- c("2010-12-21 06:00:00", "2010-12-21 09:00:00", "2010-12-21 13:00:00 ", "2010-12-23 23:00:00", "2010-12-24 02:00:00", "2010-12-25 19:00:00", "2010-12-31 08:00:00")
lagfirstvisit <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0) 
table <- cbind(ID, daytime, lagfirstvisit) 
table <- as.data.frame(table)
table$daytime <- as.POSIXct(table$daytime)
```

My aim is to generate a new column with the lag of variable `daytime` by the number as indicated in the `lagfirstvisit` column. i.e. If `lagfirstvisit == 2`, I would want the lag2 `daytime` value of the particular ID. If `lagfirstvisit == 0`, it would mean to keep the observation row's original `daytime` value.

My expected result is as follow:

```
ID <- c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300)
daytime <- c("2010-12-21 06:00:00", "2010-12-21 09:00:00", "2010-12-21 13:00:00 ", "2010-12-23 23:00:00", "2010-12-24 02:00:00", "2010-12-25 19:00:00", "2010-12-31 08:00:00")
lagfirstvisit <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0) 
result <- c("2010-12-21 06:00:00", "2010-12-21 09:00:00", "2010-12-21 06:00:00", "2010-12-23 23:00:00", "2010-12-23 23:00:00", "2010-12-25 19:00:00", "2010-12-31 08:00:00")
table.results <- cbind(ID, daytime, lagfirstvisit, result)
```

Currently, the code I am using is:

```
table <- table %>%  
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(result = lag(as.POSIXct(daytime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC"), n = as.integer(lagfirstvisit)))
```

However, I get the error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   Evaluation error: n must be a non-negative integer scalar, not integer of length 3.

Does, anyone out there know how do I resolve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [format your code appropriately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738).

Comment: As shown by your expected result, Is there a problem with `day - lagfirstvisit`

Comment: Hi guys, sorry I updated my question to reflect what I actually want to figure out. Sorry for the blunder at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    table%>%
      mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.x)))%>%#First ensure all columns are numeric
      mutate(result=day[1:n()-lagfirstvisit])# you can also use row_number() instead of 1:n()

  ID day lagfirstvisit result
1 100  21             0     21
2 100  22             0     22
3 100  23             2     21
4 200  12             0     12
5 200  13             1     12
6 300  19             0     19
7 300  22             0     22
```

Caution: Refrain from using the inbuilt function names as variable names. eg, you are not supposed to use the name `table` as this is a function in base r

EDIT:

With the new data, the procedure remains the same, as long as the `lagfirstvisit` is numeric:

```
table%>%
   mutate(result=daytime[1:n()-as.numeric(as.character(lagfirstvisit))])
   ID             daytime lagfirstvisit              result
1 100 2010-12-21 06:00:00             0 2010-12-21 06:00:00
2 100 2010-12-21 09:00:00             0 2010-12-21 09:00:00
3 100 2010-12-21 13:00:00             2 2010-12-21 06:00:00
4 200 2010-12-23 23:00:00             0 2010-12-23 23:00:00
5 200 2010-12-24 02:00:00             1 2010-12-23 23:00:00
6 300 2010-12-25 19:00:00             0 2010-12-25 19:00:00
7 300 2010-12-31 08:00:00             0 2010-12-31 08:00:00
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But i actually updated my question to reflect a change in the variable. Sorry, but would you mind helping me take a look at that as well? Thank you. Sorry I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
table.results %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    result2=mapply(`[`, list(day), row_number() - lagfirstvisit)
  )
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID   day lagfirstvisit result result2
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1  100.   21.            0.    21.     21.
2  100.   22.            0.    22.     22.
3  100.   23.            2.    21.     21.
4  200.   12.            0.    12.     12.
5  200.   13.            1.    12.     12.
6  300.   19.            0.    19.     19.
7  300.   22.            0.    22.     22.
```

Comment: This could also be done with `purrr::map` or even `sapply`.

Comment: Hi thanks! But i actually updated my question to reflect a change in the variable. Sorry, but would you mind helping me take a look at that as well? Thank you. Sorry I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: How would changing from `day` to `daytime` affect the answer? It's just simple vector indexing. Had you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little cleaner than the current answers:

```
table %>%
  group_by(ID, lagfirstvisit) %>%
  mutate(result = dplyr::lag(daytime, n = lagfirstvisit[1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Since it's grouped `lagfirstvisit` all the indexes are the same, so taking the first works ok.